# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 60000 into shape (3000,60,11)

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, training-data

there seems to be a problem while splitting my datasets into a training, testing, and validating set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/train_data1.csv"
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/train_data1.csv",  delimiter=",")
Y_train = df.iloc[:,0]
X_train = df.iloc[:,1:12]
Y_train = Y_train.values
X_train = X_train.values
print(X_train.shape)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(6000, 60, 11))
print(X_train.shape)

print(Y_train.shape)
Y_train = np.reshape(Y_train,(6000, 60, 1))
print(Y_train.shape)

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/test_data1.csv"
df= pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/test_data1.csv",  delimiter=",")
Y_test = df.iloc[:,0]
X_test = df.iloc[:,1:12]
Y_test = Y_test.values
X_test = X_test.values
X_test = np.reshape(X_test,(3000, 60, 11))
Y_test = np.reshape(Y_test,(3000, 60, 1))

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/val_data1.csv"
df= pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/val_data1.csv",  delimiter=",")
Y_val = df.iloc[:,0]
X_val = df.iloc[:,1:12]
Y_val = Y_val.values
X_val = X_val.values

Y_val = np.reshape(Y_val,(3000, 60, 11)) 
X_val = np.reshape(X_val,(3000, 60, 11))

type here
```

i was expecting to successfully split my dataset

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the only line that attempts to reshape an array into the shape (3000, 60, 11) is this one:

```py
Y_val = np.reshape(Y_val,(3000, 60, 11))
```

This line should be corrected to match the shape of the other `Y_ arrays`, which is `(N, 60, 1)`, where  (`N` is number of samples). So, the changing above line into:

```py
Y_val = np.reshape(Y_val,(3000, 60, 1))
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The aforementioned change did not fix the ValueError... Any other suggestions ? Im trying to train a RNN.

Comment: Are you facing the same error? How come?

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 660000 into shape (3000,60,11) i keep getting the same error for a certain reason, but i cant find it ?

Comment: The error message states that you cannot reshape an array of size 660000 into shape (3000, 60, 11). This error might be occurring when reshaping either X_val or Y_val. Let's verify the dimensions of the arrays before reshaping them - add this before reshaping X_val and Y_val to check their shapes:
`print("X_val shape before reshaping:", X_val.shape)
print("Y_val shape before reshaping:", Y_val.shape)`
By checking the shapes of X_val and Y_val before reshaping, we can identify where the mismatch in dimensions is occurring and troubleshoot accordingly.

Comment: the results before reshaping: X_val shape before reshaping: (60000, 11)
Y_val shape before reshaping: (60000,) How do i troubleshoot this if want to reshape the array